# Unable to schedule a Record-Triggered Flow using a Formula Date field in Salesforce

Tags: recordtriggeredflow, scheduled-flow, salesforce-flow

I have a Record-Triggered Flow on an Account with a Scheduled Path that uses a *Date Formula field* as the Time Source. Specifically, the Time Source is set to *'Start Date'* with an Offset Number of 1 minute after. However, this Scheduled Path is not being executed as expected. And I cannot see it being scheduled under Time-Based Workflow.

While debugging the flow, everything appears to be fine and is being executed.

[image]

I noticed that if I use the 'Record CreatedDate' or 'LastModifiedDate' instead of the 'Start Date' formula field, the Scheduled Path works well. And I can it scheduled under Time-Based Workflow.
[image]

Does this mean that we cannot use a Formula Date field as the Time Source for a Scheduled Path in a Record-Triggered Flow?

If anyone has faced a similar problem or has any resources or advice, I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Formula Fields in Salesforce are only calculated when you access them, so there's no concept of the value in a Formula Field changing. That means they won't run triggers when they change and they won't be able to trigger a flow either.

For example, you could have a formula field that had the formula `TIMENOW()`. It would be impossible for Salesforce to keep checking every time that formula changed its value.

Comment: In this case, flow debug is not accurate. As it's running well during debug with formula date field as a source to schedule a flow.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with fred's answer. There are [articles](https://tddprojects.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/SF/pages/1643085893/Formulas+in+Flow+Triggers) suggesting this functionality has been added but I have not found it a reliable way to run flows.
In your case, I can't think of a minute-specific flow solution. It may need an apex solution.